# Jquery - Contar cuantos UL, tienen tantos elementos LI

Tags: jquery

```js
$(function(){

 var count = '';
 var total = 1;
    
 $('ul li').each(function(index, el) {
   count++;
   if(count == 12) {
    total + 1;
   }
      
   count = '';
  });
    
    console.log('Se encontraron 2 UL con 2 li');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Tengo UL y necesito saber de todos los UL existentes, cuantos UL tienen 2 LI, lo estoy tratando de hacer con un each, será este el camino correcto.

Se encontraron 2 UL con 2 li

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Está bien con `each` ,Aquí tomo el 2 como un valor fijo , puede ser cambiado si desea buscar `ul` que contenga determinado número de `li`

```js
$(function(){
   var count=0;
   $('ul').each(function(i) {
   let len = $(this).find('li').size();
   if(len==2) count++;
    });
  console.log("SE ENCONTRARON " + count + " CON DOS LI");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta es una respuesta muy rápida, que tengas un gran día.

Comment: @Learningandsharing recuerda marcar como aceptada la respuesta si provee de una solucion a tu problema. Un saludo ^^

Answer (score 4):

Para encontrar cuantos UL hay existentes solo necesitas hacer *$("ul")* y para encontrar todos los LI aplicas algo similar: *$("li")*

Te dejo un ejemplo al respecto.

```js
var a = $("ul");
var b = $("li");

console.log("Se encontraron: "+a.size()+" UL y "+b.size()+" li");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Ahora para poder accesar a cada UL vamos hacer lo siguiente

```js
var total = 0;
$.each($("ul"), function (i,v){
if($("li",v).size() == 2){ total +=1}
});
console.log("Se encontraron "+total+" UL con 2 LI");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li>Item</li>
 <li>Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alfonso, muy claro tu ejemplo, que tengas un grand día.